# Unit Converter with the help of Xamarin Essentials coding problem

Tags: xamarin

Hi im currently programming an app where a value is given and either its converted from Celsius to fahrenheit or from fahrenheit to Celius with the help of two buttons one to convert from celsius to fahrenheit and one from fahrenheit to Celsius i wrote a code but i dont know if its correct or not the code is as follows in the cs data i made to eventhandler with the name fButton and CButton :
...

```
    private void FButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(EntryValue.Text, out int val))

        {

            var fahrenheit = UnitConverters.CelsiusToFahrenheit(val);
    }
    private void CButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(EntryValue.Text, out int val))

        {

            var celsius = UnitConverters.FahrenheitToCelsius(val);



        }
    }
}
```

...
Any suggestions thanks in advance

Comment: How is this different than the question you posted earlier, where you accepted the answer?  What is your question?  What problem are you having with the code that you posted?  Please read [ask] for guidance on how to write a good question.

Comment: the difference is that this time you give it a vlue and it doesnt convert it at the same time that means at a time it does one conversion and on another occasion the another one

Comment: The problem is that when i click one button i dont get an answer as output

Comment: Where do you expect your output? In a Label?

Comment: @adamm i have a entry placeholder where i enter a number and i have two buttons one for converting from celsius to fahrenheit and one to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius and now i want that when i click one of the button it gives me the conversion as output in a textview

Comment: Output where?  To a Label?  That is the **exact same problem** you had in your previous question, where you were doing calculations but **not updating your UI**.

Comment: I understand that, but where you expect your output? In the Entry, or you have some Label where you expect the output?

Comment: @adamm in the Entry where the TextView is

Comment: you need to include enough information in your **original post** to describe the problem you are trying to solve.  It should not take a series of 10 comments to tease this information out of you.  You could have easily said "How do I show the results of my calculations in my Entry?"  and included the relevant XAML and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the lines where you adding the calculated value to the Entry

```
        private void FButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(EntryValue.Text, out int val))

            {
                var fahrenheit = UnitConverters.CelsiusToFahrenheit(val);
                EntryValue.Text = fahrenheit.ToString();
            }
        }
        private void CButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(EntryValue.Text, out int val))

            {
                var celsius = UnitConverters.FahrenheitToCelsius(val);
                EntryValue.Text = celsius.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do i dont need this two formulas: C =(F-32)5/9 and F = C9/5+32 or does Essentials do it itself ?

Comment: Have you read the docs?  What would be the purpose of a UnitConverter class that didn't actually do unit conversion?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/unit-converters

Comment: @adamm is it possible to make a answer be visible in textview when i insert a value and click the convert button ?